# Rails and CORS: How to properly handle the initial CORS request?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cors

My `EventsController` has a single action, `create`. This is a [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/) enabled controller so it receives an HTTP `OPTIONS` request before the normal `POST` request arrives.

I do not want to save a new Event to the database when I receive the OPTIONS request but the only way I've been able to ensure that doesn't happen is by implementing what feels like a horrible hack (see my `EventsController#create` method below). What is the *right* way to handle this?

```
class API::EventsController < ApplicationController

  skip_before_filter :verify_authenticity_token
  before_filter :cors_preflight_check
  after_filter :cors_set_access_control_headers

  # If this is a preflight OPTIONS request, then short-circuit the request,
  # return only the necessary headers and return an empty text/plain.
  def cors_preflight_check
    if request.method == :options
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
      headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = 'X-Requested-With, X-Prototype-Version'
      headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = '1728000'
      render :text => '', :content_type => 'text/plain'
    end
  end

  # For all responses in this controller, return the CORS access control headers.
  def cors_set_access_control_headers
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Headers'] = "Content-Type"
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = '*'
    headers['Access-Control-Allow-Methods'] = 'POST, GET, OPTIONS'
    headers['Access-Control-Max-Age'] = "1728000"
  end

  def create
    # Is this a horrible hack?
    if request.method == "OPTIONS"
      render :json => '', :content_type => 'application/json'
      return
    end

    registered_application = RegisteredApplication.find_by(url: request.env['HTTP_ORIGIN'])

    if registered_application.nil?
      render json: "Unregistered application", status: :unprocessable_entity
    else
      event = registered_application.events.new(event_params)

      if event.save
        render json: @event, status: :created
      else
        render @event.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
      end
    end
  end

private

  def event_params
    params.permit(:name)
  end

end
```